# PivotTable.PivotFields method

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert columns in my Pivot Table by referencing the cell of the field.

According to MS help "Index Optional    Variant The name or number of the field to be returned."

So, I would like to know how to do that? I tried but it does not work.

Also I triend with the labelling.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields**.Cells(4, 176).Value, Range("Cells(4,176)"),** xlSum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "Name of the sheet", also that * to ( ), and be sure in cell (4,176) there is proper name of field, if not it won't work.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
     "PivotTable3").PivotFields(Sheets("Name of the sheet").Cells(4, 176).Value), xlSum
```

Comment: Thank you Tearmothy, do you know how to add the name of the column by referencing a cell? labelling by reference, if it is test, "Name of the column", but I want to have a cell value?

Comment: If that name is in cell (4,176) the reference to this name is in above in code. Am I understand You right?

Comment: ctiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields(Sheets("Inventory Overview - TDM").Cells(4, 148).Value), xlSum

like that the label of this column is "sum of ..."

Otherwise, ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields(Sheets("Inventory Overview - TDM").Cells(4, 148).Value), "Sales Week2" , xlSum

but, I would llike to reference this last label to a cell

Comment: For example: name = cells(4,148).value '<---Sales Week2 and put name in the place of "Sales Week2". Is it working?

Comment: Working, top Teamothy! Tyou so much!